# Where do i add Google translate plugin code to my Vue App

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, google-translate

Where do I add google translate plugin 
which has the code of the following type to my Vue App

```
 <div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'es', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Adding this to template causes error as code or tags which cause side effects are not allowed.

Can I put another script tag in a common component?

Answer (score 2):

At least two ways:

1. Short way: Put it all in `public/index.html`.
2. Long way:

Put the scripts except for the `googleTranslateElementInit()` function in `public/index.html`:

```
  <div id="google_translate_element"></div>    
     
  <script     
    type="text/javascript"     
    src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"    
  >    
  </script>
```

Then in `src/App.vue` or `src/main.js` `methods` section define the `googleTranslateElementInit()` function:

```
    googleTranslateElementInit() {
      window.google.translate.TranslateElement(
        { pageLanguage: "en" },
        "google_translate_element"
      );
    },
```

Note the extra `window` object needed.

Then call it when you're ready:

```
this.googleTranslateElementInit();
```

This long method is more flexible in that you have control on when to load the Google plugin and therefore run any other earlier code needed beforehand.

Had it all been put in index.html this would be difficult.